# displaying a model in a different model's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models so far in a rails application.

- My `User` model has fields like `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`
- My `Wallet` model has fields like `name`, `money`, `user_id`

Within the applications view, I can display my `User` by inserting

```
<h1><%= @user.first_name %></h1>
```

But am not able to display

```
<h1><%= @wallet.money %></h1>
```

I get a `no method error` in `users#show`.  I don't understand this error.

I have a method called `show` that contains `@user = User.find(params[:id])` with `params` defined in a private method below.

My question is, do I need a controller and a view for my `Wallet` model?  I didn't think I did because I am trying to display content through the applications controller. Even though the page being directed to is `Users#show`.

Ideally, since the wallet has a `user_id`, I'd love to display the money value through that... something like
`@user.wallet.money` or something... to call the money value through the foreign key associated with the current user.

Comment: Where do you define @wallet?, can ou add the controllers and/or the models if there's any relationship between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have not defined `@wallet`, hence it is `nil` and hence the error, to use the association..

In your `User` model, you need to define the association as

```
has_one :wallet
```

In your `wallet` model..

```
belongs_to :user
```

Then controller

```
@user = User.includes(:wallet).find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Now in view, you can call it as

```
@user.wallet.money
```

I suggest you to go through [`association_basics`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to understand it better and help you in future..

Comment: Ok.  But I have many wallets.  So would it be has_many: wallets and the shoiuldn't in the wallet model it be belongs_to :user  ?

Comment: ohh, you will have to loop through it then.. and associate with `has_many :wallets` do you want to display sum in all wallets?

Comment: no I just want to show the money associated  with the wallet that has the user_id of 1 if the user with id of 1 is logged into session

Comment: I want it so that a new user has the option to create a wallet.  But I want that user to be able to create a second wallet named something different to hold money reserved for a different reason.   I guess that makes no sense or is overboard.  I'm going to go with your first answer.  Thanks! only question I have is, shouldn't wallet have belongs_to :user not :wallet?

Comment: I'm getting an error now "undefined method" in my Userscontroller#show for includes

Comment: `undefined method` what?

Comment: undefined method `include' for #<User:0x0000000290a6a8>